# p.parentNode is null (no source for http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js)

Tags: jquery

On most page loads of one of my pages in Firefox 13 I get this error. (Not replicable in Chrome or Firefox 12)

p.parentNode is null
(no source for http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js)

It seems to have something to do with the CDN. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which code of yours does the error originate?

Comment: Inspect element doesn't provide any information. It clicks over to a blank page of some sort.

Comment: Place a breakpoint in the jQuery source, and examine the call stack to see where it originates in your code.